# How to check subclass in Chapel

Tags: chapel

This one is probably really stupid.  How do you check the subclass of an object in Chapel?

```
class Banana : Fruit {
  var color: string;
}
class Apple: Fruit {
  var poison: bool;
}
class Fruit {
}

var a = new Apple(poison=true);
var b = new Banana(color="green");

// ?, kinda Java-ish, what should I do?
if (type(a) == Apple.class()) {
  writeln("Go away doctor!");
}
```

Though I'm asking about a subclass, I realize I don't know how to check if it's a `Fruit` [class](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/primers/classes.html?highlight=class) either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an exact type match, you will want to write this:

```
 if (a.type == Apple) {
   writeln("Go away doctor!");
 }
```

To check if the type of `a` is a subtype of `Fruit`, this will work:

```
if (isSubtype(a.type, Fruit)) {
   writeln("Apples are fruit!");
}
```

For reference, there's a list of functions that can similarly be used to check type information [here](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/latest/modules/standard/Types.html)

*Note that the parentheses in the `if` blocks are not necessary, so you could write this instead:

```
if isSubtype(a.type, Fruit) {
   writeln("Apples are fruit!");
}
```

Comment: even MORE elegant!

Answer (score 3):

The earlier answer does a fine job of explaining the case in which the type is known at compile time, but what if it's only known at run-time?

```
class Banana : Fruit {
  var color: string;
}
class Apple: Fruit {
  var poison: bool;
}
class Fruit {
}

var a:Fruit = new Apple(poison=true);
var b:Fruit = new Banana(color="green");

// Is a an Apple?
if a:Apple != nil {
  writeln("Go away doctor!");
}
```

In this case the dynamic cast of `a` to its potential subtype `Apple` results in `nil` if it wasn't in fact an `Apple` or an expression with compile-time type `Apple` if it was.