# How to maintain sub-type of an object in a Chapel array

Tags: chapel

Following up on an [earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943288/how-to-check-subclass-in-chapel), now I want to collect the `Fruit` into a basket but know the sub-type on the way out.

```
class Banana : Fruit {
  var color: string;
}
class Apple: Fruit {
  var poison: bool;
}
class Fruit {
}

var a = new Apple(poison=true);
var b = new Banana(color="green");

if (a.type == Apple) {
  writeln("Go away doctor!");
}

var basketDom = {1..1};
var basket: [basketDom] Fruit;
basket.push_back(a);
basket.push_back(b);

for b in basket {
  writeln(b.type:string);
}
```

This prints the supertype `Fruit`.  How can I get `Apples` and `Bananas` out of this basket?

Comment: I don't know chapel, but it looks like a and b are being cast to Fruit before going in the basket.  It seems like you want something more along the lines of a java interface rather than subclassing Fruit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack (unless an actual solution to this exists) would be send a tuple into the `basket` where the tuple would represent `(type_of_object, typecasted_object)`.

Your code would hence become,

```
var basketDom = {1..1};
var basket: [basketDom] (string, Fruit);
basket.push_back((a.type:string, a));
basket.push_back((b.type:string, b));

for b in basket {
  writeln(b);
}
```

This will give you

```
(Apple, {poison = true})
(Banana, {color = green})
```

Further, you can access the types using the index. eg - `b[1]` would be the type and `b[2]` the object content.

To access the class variables such as `poison` and `color` after this, you could do something like

```
if (b[1] == "Banana") {
    var obj = b[2]: Banana;
    writeln(obj.color);
}
```

and similarily for the class `Apple`.

Comment: Instead of carrying the type along as a `string` you can use explicit casts which behave similarly to C++ `dynamic_cast`.  `if b:Apple then writeln("Apple ", b:Apple);`  If the cast fails it returns `nil` which is interpreted as `false` within the conditional.